# ElectronNet with .net core 3.0 Sqlite can not find table

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, electron, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm using Electron.Net with .Net Core 3.0

When I start the project by using IIS I had not any error. But when I start the application with using Electron I'm getting "no such table" error.

[Electron starting with error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL44a.png)

```
 services.AddDbContext<MainDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=sqliteKron.db"));
```

My sqlite file is under solution main path.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I almost fixed but new case is; when I start from Electron this query is working but returning just 0. It's really funny Electron!!!

 : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "name" = '__EFMigrationsHistory' AND "type" = 'table';

Comment: Are you sure you are querying the db that have the migrations implemented? Did you put the db file properties to copy always, so the db is copied to bin folder?